# ASCII of integer to integer in Arduino

Tags: arduino, lorawan

I am working on a project with LoRa and Arduino and I am facing a weird issue where when I transmit a integer the receiver receives at ASCII value which is not good at my case because I wanted to transmit sensor data(3 digits) which is not possible by ASCII. I will also attach my code(converted into a basic integer code for testing) I need a Solution to fix this BTW I am using Arduino UNO for transmitting and Arduino Mega for receiving and SX1278 LoRa Module for both transmitting and receiving.

Transmitter Code(Arduino UNO):

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <LoRa.h>
    
    int val = 5;
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      while (!Serial);
    
      Serial.println("LoRa Sender");
    
      if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
        Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
        while (1);
      }
    }
    
    void loop() {
      Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
    
      // send packet
      LoRa.beginPacket();
      LoRa.print(val);
      LoRa.endPacket();
    
      delay(500);
    }
```

Receiver Code(Arduino Mega):

```
   #include <SPI.h>
   #include <LoRa.h>
   
   #define LORA_SS 53
   #define LORA_RST 9
   #define LORA_DIO0 8
   int val;
   
   void setup() {
     pinMode(LORA_SS, OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(LORA_SS, HIGH);
   
     LoRa.setPins(LORA_SS, LORA_RST, LORA_DIO0);
     Serial.begin(9600);
     
     while (!Serial);
   
     Serial.println("LoRa Receiver");
   
     if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
       Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
       while (1);
     }
   }
   
   void loop() {
     // try to parse packet
     int packetSize = LoRa.parsePacket();
     if (packetSize) {
       // received a packet
       Serial.print("Received packet '");
   
       // read packet
       while (LoRa.available()) {
         //Serial.print((char)LoRa.read());
         int val = LoRa.read();
        
       }
      
       Serial.print(val);
       // print RSSI of packet
       Serial.print("' with RSSI ");
       Serial.println(LoRa.packetRssi());
     }
   }
```

Output of the receiver :

```
Received packet '53' with RSSI -5
```

Comment: use `Serial.write` instead of `Serial.print`.  `Serial.print(2)` sends `'2'` whereas `Serial.write(2)` sends `2`

Comment: Use [Lora.write(byte)](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa/blob/master/src/LoRa.h#L49), this is applicable to all classes that is inherited from Stream class (such as Serial, Lora, Print classes) where `write()` send data in byte, `print()` convert the byte into ASCII.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying and I have tried it (Used Lora.write() insted of Lora.print()) but now the value is being printed as 0 here is the output :
 `Received packet '0' with RSSI -12`
But the value which  i am sending is 5

I have also tried **Sembei Norimaki** answer But i am gettin no value here is the output when  print with Serial.write() insted of Serial.print() :
 `Received packet ' ' with RSSI -12`

Comment: Can you please help me with it

Comment: You have a conversion problem. Basically the way data is sent via communication ports on such as UART which is the way you're LoRa module is probably connected to you're microcontroller, is in ASCII format this means each character either it is a number or a letter is sent as a char which is the same as a byte. This means you have to convert each chararacter received from its ASCII id to its string value then concatenate them and then convert them to an int.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me! I have figured out how to fix it! I sent it as an integer and saved it as a string in the receiver and used `.toInt();` to convert it back to integer and I am good with it! Again Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Fix this issue just send the value as an integer, since LoRa receives as char/string same it in a string variable in the receiver and convert it into integer with `toInt();` and that will fix it!